# How to setup: Cygwin + Vim = IDE for Ruby, Python and other programming languages?

Tags: ruby, windows, vim, ide, cygwin

I primarily use Linux at home but I have a Windows (XP) machine at work. So now I've got Cygwin setup and I'm interested in some Ruby programming at this point in time. I also use the Vim editor on my Linux machine so I'd like to use it as the editor on Cygwin. I'd also like Vim to be my IDE when I code Ruby stuff. I've read that this can be done although I am unsure how this all can setup in Cygwin (i.e. should I just install plugins? or do I need to compile Vim in Cygwin?)

Can someone help me setup Vim in Cygwin so that it can be used as an IDE for Ruby (and perhaps Python and other programming languages>?

```
- Cygwin version is 2.764
- Ruby (in Cygwin) version is 1.8.7
```

Update: What I am specifically looking for is to get something similar to installing `vim-ruby` or `vim-nox` in Debian.

Comment: No need to compile vim for Cygwin: it's already done. You should be able to select it from the package list in [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/install.html).

Comment: @me_and I tried that earlier. What I did was to install Ruby for Cygwin first. Then I installed the binary for Vim for Cygwin. When I got into Vim, I entered the ff. code: `puts "hello, ruby"`And then I tried issuing the `:rubyf hello.rb` command in Vim and I got the ff. error: `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version`

So I guess I need to recompile?

Comment: Your question still asks whether you need to compile vim in Cygwin. What it looks like you're after is configuration instructions to be able to use vim as a Ruby IDE. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Cygwin for all this, you can just use the native Windows versions of everything:

- [Vim for Windows](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc)
- [Ruby for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/)

Then from Vim you can issue `:!ruby hello.rb` to execute the file (assuming the Ruby exe's are in your PATH).

Since this isn't gvim/Windows-specific you should be able to also issue this command from your CLI+Cygwin Vim and it should still work.

Comment: I want to get something similar to the effect of installing `vim-ruby` or `vim-nox` in Debian. Is that possible in Cygwin?

Comment: What `vim-ruby` and `vim-nox` do is allow you to write Vim _plugins_ using Ruby instead of Vimscript. Is that what you mean? Or are you just interested in using Vim to write Ruby code for something other than Vim plugins?

Comment: It's the latter -- write Ruby code for something other than Vim plugins. I guess your answer makes sense to me now. Thanks for pointing out what `vim-ruby` and `vim-nox` are for (I didn't know that).

Comment: You don't need `vim-ruby` or `vim-nox` to code Ruby using Vim regardless of your OS. Whenever you open a `.rb` in Vim it should automatically have syntax-highlighting, etc.